# coding in java with OJDBC14.jar

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I had installed ojdbc14.jar, and I was trying to code a basic connection with it:

```
import java.sql.*;

class OracleCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "oracle");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
            while (rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  " + rs.getString(3));

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this the class is being created at compile-time. When i am trying to run it, there is an error.

> ERROR:could not find or load main class oraclecon

What is the problem?

Comment: You aren't running it correctly; **how** *precisely* are you attempting to run it? Note that `oraclecon` != `OracleCon`

Comment: You forgot to compile the class, or you forgot to put the .class file on the classpath.

Comment: You need to compile and  run with the proper class name,I guess you are using the class name as `oraclecon` rather than `OracleCon `